# val() returns Placeholder value instead of the actual value in IE8,9 when the field is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

Placeholder attribute shown below works fine in firefox but if val() is called when the field is **empty** it returns the placeholder value instead of the actual value in the text.

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Jrfwr/2/

```
<input id="tlt" type="text" placeholder="Enter Title" />
```

JSCode

```
function placeHolderFallBack() {
   if ("placeholder" in document.createElement("input")) {
       return;
   }
   else {
       $('[placeholder]').focus(function () {
           var input = $(this);
           if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
               input.val('');
               input.removeClass('placeholder');
           }
       }).blur(function () {
           var input = $(this);
           if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
               input.addClass('placeholder');
               input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
           }
       }).blur();
       $('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function () {
           $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function () {
               var input = $(this);
               if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                   input.val('');
               }
           })
       });
   }
}
```

Comment: And what's the question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could override the val() method but I don't like doing that :D

I wrote a simple `pVal()` function which does the job

```
$.fn.pVal = function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        val = $this.eq(0).val();
    if(val == $this.attr('placeholder'))
        return '';
    else
        return val;
}
$(function(){
    alert($('input').val())
    alert($('input').pVal())
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W7JKt/3/

Comment: what if someone decides to write what the placeholder says?

Comment: Then it's replaced. Or do you think it might be something useful? As long as you choose a good placeholder text it shouldn't happen

Comment: i just think its a problem that it can happen, its not that important to me i just think that one should always attempt to make code that cant create problems for the user and i see a potential of problems here. But again thats just my opinion and i don't really have any interest in the question.

Answer (score 3):

In your JSFiddle code you get the value of the textbox in a BUTTON CLICK event... and your code that checks if the current value of the textbox is equal to the placeholder executes in the FORM SUBMIT event.

So... the problem is that the BUTTON's CLICK event executes before the FORM's SUBMIT event.

[This code shows an example of how to get the correct value](http://jsfiddle.net/paTZm/5/)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Its to do with HTML 5. Please see this article.

http://www.cssnewbie.com/cross-browser-support-for-html5-placeholder-text-in-forms/